# Isn't reflexivity and symmetry implied in equivalence relations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

It looks like for all "nice" sets, the set $S\times S$ will have symmetry and reflexivity by default. The tough part is usually showing transitivity. However, are there any non-empty sets such that $S\times S$ is not symmetric and reflexive?

Comment: What exactly is the equivalence relation you're working with here?

Comment: The set $S\times S$ is always an equivalence relation, and is reflexive, symmetric, _and_ transitive: it is the relation that says that every element of $S$ is related to every element of $S$.  Perhaps you meant something else? Some subset of $S\times S$ perhaps?

Comment: If you take $S \times S $ to be the (equivalence) relation then it will always be trivially reflexive, symmetric and transitive for any set $S$. It is only when you take a non-trivial relation that this might not happen.

Comment: @MJD I am afraid you answered my question.

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: A quick way to see that this is an equivalence relation is to note that any element of S is related to any other element, so the relation SxS will generate a partition on S, which is {S} itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The set $S\times S$ is always an equivalence relation, and is reflexive, symmetric, *and* transitive: it is the relation that says that every element of $S$ is related to every element of $S$.

---

To answer your question from the comments, suppose we have some set $S$, and we have a relation on $S$, say $\sim$.  We want to represent $\sim$ as a subset $R_\sim\subset S\times S$, and your question is which subset $R_\sim$ corresponds to the relation $\sim$.  The correspondence is very straightforward: We have $a \sim b$ if and only if $\langle a,b\rangle \in R_\sim$.

For example, let $R_\le$ be the subset of $\Bbb Z\times \Bbb Z$ that represents the $\le$ relation.  Then $\langle 1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 1,17\rangle$ and $\langle 9,9\rangle$ are elements of $R_\le$, because $1\le2$ and $1\le 17$ and $9\le 9$, but $\langle 3,1\rangle$ is not because $3\not\le 1$.

---

When $R = S\times S$, we have that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$ for all $a$ and $b$, and so the relation represented by this $R$ has $a\sim b$ for all $a$ and $b$—that is, $a$ and $b$ are *always* related. It should be easy to prove that this relation is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  Similarly, when $R = \emptyset$, we get the relation where $a$ and $b$ are *never* related, which is symmetric and transitive, but not reflexive.

Comment: So when I see $b \in X, a \sim b$, I should be thinking what? Because I understand that $\sim$ is a set, but what does it mean for $a$ and $b$ to be related in that way?

Comment: @SalmonKiller That needs some context. The point here is that certain *subsets* of $S \times S$ may fail reflexivity and symmetry.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein The context is equivalence classes. They are defined as $\lbrace x \in X; a\sim x \rbrace$

Comment: That's the definition of the equivalence class containing $a$ (assuming an equivalence relation on $X$). The equivalence classes partition $X$, meaning that $X$ is the disjoint union of those equivalence classes.

Comment: Can you clarify what it means for a Cartesian product to be an equivalence relation? I don't understand. Edit: Now I see it. Thanks. I've never seen this notation before!